# While looping results one at a time

Tags: php

I apologize if my title is not prefect. Let me try to explain...

I am creating an array from a database. If you take a look at $result3 you will notice it's placed inside a while loop (with [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)). What the while loop is doing is that it's placing the $records2 and $result3 in every 10th position using modulus.

The problem I'm facing is that I still need $result2 and $result3 to loop though and placed in every 10th position **BUT** I need it to do it one at a time for only $result3

For example:
https://codeshare.io/5PYk0Y

**Here is my table:**
[image]

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, volume, name, content, image, cssanimate, group_name FROM weekly_live ORDER BY id ");
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, volume, name, content, image, cssanimate, group_name FROM weekly_live_photos_users_saved_data WHERE username = '".$users_dir_base_name."' ORDER BY position");
$result3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT name, cssanimate, source FROM motion_presentation_videos ORDER BY id "); 



$records2 = array();
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $records2[] = array('tags' => array($row2));
    }

$records3 = array();
    while ($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        $records3[] = array('tags' => array($row3));
    }



 $counter = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $counter++;
        if(($counter % 10 == 0) || $counter==1 ) { 
            $records = array_merge($records, $records3);
            $records = array_merge($records, $records2);
        }
        $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
    }
```

Any help is appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: Your question/problem isn't very clear. Can you explain the problem and your desired results differently?

Comment: @waterloomatt thank for you the reply! So sorry. If you look inside the while loop you'll see $records = array_merge($records, $records3); I need to keep what it's currently doing (which is using the modulus division operator) but instead of calling the whole $records3 at once together (for example: https://codeshare.io/2WYNZW) I wanna call one by one and place $records3 in position 1....10....20...30...40...50...etc

Comment: Are you, in fact, trying to do groupings with headings?

Comment: I need to use the modulus division operator but also add something where it does 1.mp4, then the next 10th position is 2.mp4, then the next 10th position 3.mp4 and so on... because right now it's just doing 1.mp4, 2.mp4, 3.mp4, 4.mp4, 5.mp4...

Comment: @waterloomatt Here is what I am trying to do.. https://codeshare.io/5w6dpx and here is what is currently happening - which is wrong! https://codeshare.io/ad9Ygg

Answer (score 1):

You get all the mp4s added every 10 times because that is what you coded.  This line:

```
$records = array_merge($records, $records3);
```

adds *all* the entries from *$records3* all at once.

You should keep a separate counter variable to add only a single entry from *$records3*:

```
 $counter = 0;
 $counter2 = 0;
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $counter++;
    if(($counter % 10 == 0) || $counter==1 ) { 
        $counter2++;
        $records = array_merge($records, $records3[$counter2]);
        $records = array_merge($records, $records2);
    }
    $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
  }
```

Comment: Hey Jams! Thank for you the reply :) I see what you mean. I replaced my while loop code with yours and I got an error/warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array. Weird?

Comment: I fixed the warning. I feel like this is close but it's only adding the one entry (the very last entry in the database) and I need it to add all of the entries from $record3 but separate them in order. For example: 1.mp4 -1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10   2.mp4 -1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10   3.mp4 -1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10 ....etc